# Store data of an application?

Tags: java, android

I am looking for a good possibility to store data online. I am programming with Java and Android. So there should be an interface to get access to these data. The most files are images. There is an increasing number of images. One image has a file size of nearly 200kb.

What is a common way to store these data? I need a good performance. So there should be a fast response and unlimited traffic. Maybe you can show me some options for secure data storage.

I have looked for webservers to store data. But many of these do not allow to store application data like images.

Comment: Android can do very well with php. you can use mysql or other sql database on the server to store data. and believe me it is efficient. You can have many tutorials online about this perticular subject. I once tried to use CRUD operation through android and manage online mysql database. It is a simple process and can be used  efficiently.

Comment: What about the file size in a database (MySQL)? Will it be lower than 200kb per image? Whould you recommend blob?

Comment: I guess It depends on the the server provider. I have my own server and have't faced that problem using phpMyadmin

Comment: I would not like to store images in a database because it is a bad practice. Storing the reference to the file should be a better solution because of the file size. But where should the images be stored?

Comment: Unlimited traffic sounds pretty expensive. Are you trying to create a cloud server for users to upload and download files? Or is this for updates of your application dynamically?

Comment: It should be a social network. And there would be much traffic (many profiles = many profile pictures)

Comment: Good implementations of something like this would use a combination of a database (and/or external file repository) hosted by servers, with local caching on the device of content that the user seems to access frequently.

Comment: That is how I would like to do it. Do you have any suggestions for good and not expensive servers? Do they have a special name?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you don't want to use DB for storing images. Ok, so the solution is to use file storage. You may want to take a look on the [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (to my mind, great solution for storing static content) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage/)